# Python threading and SQL

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, optimization

My questions basically is is there a best practice approach to db interaction and am I doing something silly / wrong in the below that is costing processing time.

My program pulls data from a website and writes to a SQL database. Speed is very important and I want to be able to refresh the data as quickly as possible. I've tried a number of ways and I feel its still way too slow - i.e. could be much better with a better approach / design to interaction with the db and I'm sure I'm making all sorts of mistakes. I can download the data to memory very quickly but the writes to the db take much much longer.

The 3 main approaches I've tried are:

- Threads that pull the data and populate a list of SQL commands, when
  threads complete run sql in main thread
- Threads that pull data and push to SQL (as per below code)
- Threads that pull data and populate a q with separate thread(s)
  polling the q and pushing to the db.

Code as below:

```
import MySQLdb as mydb

class DatabaseUtility():
    def __init__(self):
        """set db parameters"""

    def updateCommand(self, cmd):
        """run SQL commands and return number of matched rows"""
        try:
            self.cur.execute(cmd)
            return int(re.search('Rows matched: (\d+)', self.cur._info).group(1))
        except Exception, e:
            print ('runCmd error: ' + str(e))
            print ('With SQL: ' + cmd)
            return 0

    def addCommand(self, cmd):
        """write SQL command to db"""
        try:
            self.cur.execute(cmd)
            return self.cur.rowcount
        except Exception, e:
            print ('runCmd error: ' + str(e))
            print ('With SQL: ' + cmd)
            return 0
```

I've created a class that instantiates a db connection and is called as below:

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import urllib2
import json
from databasemanager import DatabaseUtility as dbU
from datalinks import getDataLink, allDataLinks

numThreads = 3
q = Queue()
dbu = dbU()

class OddScrape():
    def __init__(self, name, q):
        self.name = name
        self.getOddsData(self.name, q)

    def getOddsData(self, i, q):
        """Worker thread - parse each datalink and update / insert to db"""
        while True:
            #get datalink, create db connection
            self.dbu = dbU()
            matchData = q.get()   

            #load data link using urllib2 and do a bunch of stuff 
            #to parse the data to the required format

            #try to update in db and insert if not found
            sql = "sql to update %s" %(params)
            update = self.dbu.updateCommand(sql)
            if update < 1:
                sql = "sql to insert" %(params)
                self.dbu.addCommand(sql)  
        q.task_done()
        self.dbu.dbConClose()
        print eventlink

def threadQ():
    #set up some threads
    for i in range(numThreads):
        worker = Thread(target=OddScrape, args=(i, q,))
        worker.start()
    #get urldata for all matches required and add to q
    matchids = dbu.runCommand("sql code to determine scope of urls")
    for match in matchids:
        sql = "sql code to get url data %s" %match
        q.put(dbu.runCommand(sql))
    q.join()
```

I've also added an index to the table I'm writing too which seemed to help a tiny bit but not noticeably:

```
CREATE INDEX `idx_oddsdata_bookid_datalinkid` 
ON `dbname`.`oddsdata` (bookid, datalinkid) COMMENT '' ALGORITHM DEFAULT LOCK DEFAULT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple threads implies multiple connections.  Although getting a connection is "fast" in MySQL, it is not instantaneous.  I do not know the relative speed of getting a connection versus running a query, but I doubt if you multi-threaded idea will win.

Could you show us examples of the actual queries (SQL, not python code) you need to run.  We may have suggestions on combining queries, improved indexes, etc.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, too.  (You mentioned a `CREATE INDEX`, but it is useless out of context.)

It looks like you are doing a multi-step process that could be collapsed into `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`.